# SharePoint Foundation: Copy site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, site-template

Is there the option to save site as template in SP 2013 foundation? The option for me is unavailable even though I am a site collection admin.

Currently the subsite needs to be copied over to another location (not moved permanently), is there a way to do this with powershell commands? And is there an example of this?

I've had a quick search and found this article: http://www.sharepoint.inf4web.com/326/how-to-import-export-sharepoint-subsite/

Does an import copy or move the subsite?
And would I need to export and import or just import to a new subsite?
Many Thanks.

Comment: Do you have Publishing feature on for the site collection?

Comment: no, which is what I checked along with the permissions. Are there any other features preventing the option?

Comment: Not sure about any other feature, publishing is the culprit most of the times..

Comment: have just gone with the stsadm commands, slightly annoying but there you go

Answer (score 0):

If Publishing Feature was activated at any point and then deactivated it creates the "Site Pages" Library.

You could try to append savetmpl.aspx to the URL.

(i.e. `http:// Your_Site_Web /_layouts/15/savetmpl.aspx`)

You should be able to copy the site using the "Content and Structure" found under the "Site Settings"

If this does not help you could always copy the site using SharePoint Designer

Answer (score 0):

It is little strange that you are not getting the saveastemplate link because their is no publishing feature in SPF version.

- You can try directly to go the saveastemplate page as Vince2322589 mentioned in his reply.

**For Export & Import.**

- You have to Run Export first using [Export-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895(v=office.15).aspx)
- you have to run the import using [Import-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613(v=office.15).aspx)

while you performing export & import process, it copy the site not move. that's mean you have site on source and destination after successful import.